# "Invalid API request" when using CURL_EXEC

Tags: php, api, curl

i have the following php code that calls an API:

```
$forcetest = 1;

$url = "https://www.website.com/api/pointTotal.php?userId=" . $userId;
if ($forcetest || (isset($_SERVER['ON_TEST_SERVER']) && ($_SERVER['ON_TEST_SERVER']))){
    $url = "https://wwwtest.website.com/api/pointTotal.php?userId=" . $userId;
}

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'sharedSecret: abc123',
));

//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); //tested to see if this would work, didn't seem to matter

// Only do this if on dev/test
if ($forcetest || (isset($_SERVER['ON_TEST_SERVER']) && ($_SERVER['ON_TEST_SERVER']))) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
}

$response = curl_exec($curl);
print($response);
if(!$response){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}
```

my problem is when going to production (i.e. `$forcetest = 0;`) it works just fine, calling the prod api and using the prod database. if i switch it, and it goes to the wwwtest subdomain to call the test api, i get the error returned
`{"success":false,"errors":["Invalid API request"]}`

"invalid api request" isn't something in the api's code, so it seems to me that its something curl_exec is doing/erroring on but i can't figure out what. if i go to the api's directly, they both return the correct information in my browser, so i know it's up and working. is it maybe a cert issue or some sort of xss setting on that subdomain/server that's causing it to error? i'm kind of at a loss.

Thanks in advance.

edit: CLI curl command and header output:

```
[josh@mac] $ curl -H 'sharedSecret: abc123' 'https://wwwtest.website.com/api/pointTotal.php?userId=1472&rewardsType=f' -vvv
* About to connect() to wwwtest.website.com port 443
*   Trying xxx.xx.xx.xx... connected
* Connected to wwwtest.website.com (xxx.xx.xx.xx) port 443
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv2, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
SSL connection using RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: /C=US/ST=New Mexico/L=Albuquerque/O=removed/CN=*.website.com
*    start date: 2013-07-29 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2016-10-05 12:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: wwwtest.website.com matched
*    issuer: /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert Secure Server CA
* SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /api/pointTotal.php?userId=1472&rewardsType=f HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Host: wwwtest.website.com
> Accept: */*
> sharedSecret: abc123
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 29 Jun 2016 18:27:25 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
< Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, auth-key
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://customeraccess.website.com
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: sharedSecret
< Content-Length: 36
< Content-Type: text/html
Connection #0 to host wwwtest.website.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"userId":"1472","pointTotal":50600}
```

also added this to the php code making the call

`curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)` and it prints out a `404` which is what seems to be the problem but going to the url it's curl'ing immediatley returns the correct result so i'm not sure what's causing the 404

Comment: Are you sure that wwwtest.website.com/api/epson/pointTotal.php endpoint is really reachable? As solution I would recommend to convert to CLI form and debug if first point is not help. Use -vvv as more verbose

Comment: @Rinat i checked the `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` and it turns out it is reaching a 404, but i'm not sure why because i printed out the `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` and it's where i expected it to go and it looks like it's accessible from my browser. so that explains the invalid call response. not sure why it's getting that though. i'm not sure what you mean by CLI form though.

Comment: I mean write curl -H 'sharedSecret: abc123' 'your url' -vvv and run in shell

Comment: @Rinat edited post with the output from that command. seems to work exactly right via CLI. it's only on the website i'm getting the 404.

Comment: Can you hardcode url in php-code $url, to make sure that it is exactly the same?

Comment: @Rinat yeah i just did

`$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://wwwtest.website.com/api/pointTotal.php?userId=1472&rewardsType=f"
    ));`

same results. broken with wwwtest, works with www, both work in browser. returning 404's on wwwtest.

Comment: and still the same ?

Comment: @Rinat yes same. sorry, i messed up submitting that comment originally.

Comment: in this case it looks like subdomain certificate issue. May be check this one idea  http://www.net24.co.nz/kb/article/AA-00246/21/Shared-Hosting/PHP/How-to-use-CURL-with-PHP-to-get-content-from-SSL-enabled-sites.html

Comment: @Rinat that's basically what i was avoiding by using
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);`
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

when i remove those i get
`"SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed" - Code: 60`

Comment: is it possible to check without SSL - just with http://... To clarify does it relate concern subdomain or not?

Comment: @Rinat it is not, it forwards back to https. i did verify via commandline that i am getting 404's from some servers but not from other servers, so it appears to be some sort of configuration thing. i'm gonna hand off the header response calls for each server from your -vvv recommendation to the sysadmins and see if they can come up with something. thank you, i'll let you know if they find anything.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, just now saw this question was still open. The problem turned out to be bad internal DNS. the code and the curl we're all correct, i had to rely on the sys admin's to resolve it.